# Question about defining potential energy of a magnetic dipole placed in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential-energy

We know that magnetic field is a non-conservative field, since it exists in closed loops.

Then how can we define the potential energy of a magnetic dipole placed in a magnetic field ?

Comment: See http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node38.html

Comment: We talk about forces being non conservative, it doesn't matter if the magnetic field has closed loops, firstly it isn't bad force field, secondly the force depends on velocity so the conservative nonconservative doesn't apply. So it's not clear what your problem is with dipoles in magnetic fields.

Comment: Where do you get the magnetic field to be non-conservative?

Comment: can you please clarify whether the Magnetic field is a conservative or a non-conservative force field ? because I was told that it is a non conservative field..

Comment: Check out the answer to the following question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301195/how-is-it-possible-to-define-a-potential-energy-of-a-magnetic-dipole-if-bfb